# autoLink with onClick event

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink, autolink

I have a list of web address display in a `ListView`. Each item of `ListView` have a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. `TextView` have attribute `autolink="web"`.

I also have event: `onItemLongClick` in this `ListView` to open details of each others. But when I do long click event on each item in list, they do open new page also open browser with link website in `TextView`.

How can I set when `onItemLongClick`, the `TextView` can't click into link? I try set `TextView.setLinkClickable(false)` but it isn't working.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in this way.

1. on your *.xml*, add this to the `TextView` :

   TextView
   ...
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:textIsSelectable="true"
2. on your code use `ListView` click behavior and longClick behavior.

Comment: I've tried it with Android Studio on real device with MM. Please post some code, maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @TrươngVũNgọc my bad, avoid inserting textView.setLinksClickable(false); . I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think problem has resolved when I try your code yesterday (modify little bit).

Comment: @TrươngVũNgọc good! Don't hesitate to post your final solution ;-) .

Answer (score 1):

U can try Using :-

```
 Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: Sorry, i think you missed my question. Btw, it's not work

Answer (score 0):

In your `onItemLongClick()` method, return `true` to indicate that you have consumed the click event and it should not be passed on to any other listeners.

According to the docs, the return value is described as -

> **boolean**   true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise

Returning true will **NOT** pass the long click event, which is also a click event, to the `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: That's how it should work, but unfortunately it doesn't in practice. The xml attribute runs independently of whether the longClick returns true.